# ¿Cómo puedo excluir un subdirectorio al crear un archivo tar?

Tags: unix, tar, solaris

Intento hacer un archivo tar en Solaris pero quiero que una de las subcarpetas no entre en el archivo tar.

Ejemplo

```
tar -cvf nombre.tar.gz directorio_a_empaquetar.
```

Dentro del directorio hay un subdirectorio que no debo comprimir, he tratado con `X` y `-X` pero no me funciona, tambien con `--exclude`.

Comment: ¿Cómo has utilizado `--exclude` exactamente? Debe ser `--exclude=/nombre/del/directorio`.

Answer (score 2):

La opción `--exclude` está disponible en la implementación de GNU, pero no en la de Solaris.

Tengo entendido que puedes usar GNU `tar` usando el comando `gtar` o el modificador `X` en la versión de Solaris ([según la documentación oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54763/tar-1.html)):

> **`X`**
>
> Exclude. Use the `exclude-file` argument as a file containing a list of relative path names for files (or directories) to be excluded from the tarfile when using the functions `c`, `x`, or `t`. Be careful of trailing white spaces. Also beware of leading white spaces, since, for each line in the excluded file, the entire line (apart from the newline) is used to match against the initial string of files to exclude. Lines in the exclude file are matched exactly, so an entry like “`/var`” does **not** exclude the `/var` directory if `tar` is backing up relative pathnames. The entry should read “`./var`” under these circumstances. The `tar` command does not expand shell metacharacters in the exclude file, so specifying entries like “`*.o`” does not have the effect of excluding all files with names suffixed with “`.o`”. If a complex list of files is to be excluded, the exclude file should be generated by some means such as the `find`(1) command with appropriate conditions.
>
> Multiple `X` arguments can be used, with one exclude-file per argument. In the case where included files (see `−I` `include-file` operand) are also specified, the excluded files take precedence over all included files. If a file is specified in both the `exclude-file` and the `include-file` (or on the command line), it is excluded.

Toma en cuenta que **el operando `exclude-file` no es el nombre del archivo/directorio que quieras excluir, sino un archivo de texto donde incluyas las rutas (una por línea) de los archivos/directorios que quieras excluir**. Si ya habías usado el modificador `X` y no funcionó, es probable que haya sido por esta razón.

La sintaxis sería esta:

```
tar cvfX tar-file exclude-file file...
```

Y si usas algún intérprete con [*process substitution*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) (como alguna versión moderna de Bash o Zsh) también puedes usar:

```
tar cvfX tar-file <(echo /path/to/dir) file...
```